# Selecting the Nth element of an xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, random

I use the following php code to get a random amount of URL's form an xpath query:

```
@$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $rawPage );
@$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
@$itemCells = $xpath->query( "//td[@width=120]/a" );
```

I need to pick a url randomly from that pool so I can visit it via cURL.

What I would like to do is get the count of how many URL's are found so I can use that as the max in a `rand( 0 , $itemCells->length )`

However it tells me that `$itemCell` **Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array** and that my rand() **rand() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given**

Perhaps there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: Did you try saving the value from `->length` into a local variable first? `$max = $itemCells->length; $rand = rand( 0, $max);`. Then you should be able to do `$random_node = $itemCells->item( $rand);`.

Comment: Thanks @nickb, that appears to take care of the random() problem. However, the $itemCell problem still exists.

Comment: What is the problem with `$itemCell` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that since `$length` is a `readonly` property, you'd run into trouble passing it to a function. So, the solution is to save the `$length` value from a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist) to a local variable first, then call [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand), like so:

```
$max = $itemCells->length; 
$rand = rand( 0, $max);
```

Then you should be able to do this to grab a random node from the list:

```
$random_node = $itemCells->item( $rand);
```

And from there, to grab the URL, you would do:

```
$url = $random_node->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, now how do I add the url retrieval part to $itemCells->item ( $rand);

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it does not work for you, please let me know.

Comment: Brilliant! ->nodeValue is the correct way if you want to update your answer. :)

Comment: I believe `$node->getAttribute('href')` has the same effect as `$node->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue` (see http://php.net/domelement.getattribute ).

Comment: @Phoenix - Good point - It will if the DOMNodeList contains DOMElement objects. I'm not sure which is the case, so I went with DOMNode, which was guaranteed to work.